# Is technology a mass noun?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

I am wondering if the sentence below is correct:

> The company transferred critical 5G technologies to one of its
>   partners in order to make it's supply chain more efficient.

Can you also use it without an s to mean the exact same thing?

I hear both of them, so I thought they were synonymous.

> The company transferred critical 5G technology to one of its partners
>   in order to make it's supply chain more efficient.

Also, do you need to put an article before, like "the"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Technology** *can* be a mass noun, or a countable noun. There is a subtle difference.

As a **mass noun**, it refers to technology in the abstract. "5G technology", as a mass noun phrase, refers to all technology related to 5G as one collective abstract, or (depending on context) to some unspecified element of technology related to 5G.

As a **countable noun**, it refers to a discrete element of technology. For example,  **one** 5G technology might be the so-called "Massive MIMO" antennae.

In practice, these will often be interchangeable, but there is a difference in meaning.

Oh, and whether or not you need an article depends on context. In both of your examples, there's no need for an article.